# Convert .doc and .txt format file into pdf file for for .aspnet?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, pdf

I really try to find on google how can we convert .doc and .txt file into pdf file but
not getting required answer or code.

I want any command line software of converter code which will provide code that convert above to format file into pdf file.

if any user upload upload .txt and .doc file then it will be convert into .pdf file in my application.

so need coversion code.

and after coverting into pdf when i clicked on it. it will be open into pdf in browser.

Need help and code and explanation to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This topic (actually both topics - PDF generation and sending a PDF stream or file in the response) have been discussed quite a lot on SO. Just do a quick search for ["asp net pdf generation"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp+net+pdf+generation).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article on code project, http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/convertdocintootherformat.aspx it shows how to convert a doc to rtf using C# you should be able to adapt this to convert to text