# How to convert document to PDF by using CutePdf writer?

Tags: c#, pdf

The requirement is to convert documents(.doc & .rtf) files to PDF format.But I shouldn't use any Openoffice, Itextsharp or even interop dll's while due to unavailability of license issue. The management suggested using CutePDF writer might be able to convert.

I installed CutePDF writer, set it as a default printer. The whole day I googled for this, I didn't find any cute PDF programmatical interface(like .dll) to use in the C# code. Can anyone guide this how to do? or suggest me if it is not possible to convert by using cute pdf writer which is a correct way or not.

Comment: Did you look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672856/convert-word-document-to-pdf-using-cutepdf-programatically-in-c-sharp)?

Comment: @ButI'mNotAWrapperClass , Not previously. Just I have read it. It seems the conversion is not possible with CutePDF writer directly.

Comment: @ButI'mNotAWrapperClass The (only and unaccepted) answer there suggests you have to buy a tool from them, while OP's management seems to be heading for the "we rather pay our devs than pay for licenses" road. :|

Comment: @gopim Is there actually a DLL for CutePDF? You could try to use [reflection](https://stackify.com/what-is-c-reflection/) to try to create instances of the classes mentioned in the [Custom PDF Writer](http://www.cutepdf.com/products/sdk/pdfwriter3.asp). The issue with this is that it may not be allowed  due to the licensing.

Comment: @ButI'mNotAWrapperClass, I didn't find any libraries or .dll inside of CutePDF writer 
 installed files. Today I found one more reference that is CutePDF writer doesn't have any programmatic interface.
https://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3398378/Re-How-to-use-CutePDF-Writer-programmatically.aspx